# uWSGI + Nginx, uWSGI can't receive request

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I'm using uWSGI + Nginx to deploy a Django app. But uWSGI can't receive any request from Nginx.

```
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0x8e7250 pid: 20440 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 20440)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 20445, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 20446, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 20447, cores: 1)
... no requests seen
```

Here's the my config files:

uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
chdir           = /home/laike9m/Envs/blog/My_Blog
module          = my_blog.wsgi:application
home            = /home/laike9m/Envs/blog/
master          = true
processes       = 3
socket          = /tmp/uwsgi.sock
chmod-socket    = 664
vacuum          = true
```

nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;

    location /media {
        alias /home/laike9m/media;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/laike9m/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock;
        include uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

If you visit http://107.170.253.157/, it will give you 502 error.
In Nginx's log:

```
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 545 "-"
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: what is the permission on the socket file? also try using ports temporarily?

Comment: @user2707389 I didn't say "permission denied" or something like that, so I don't think it's because permission. The sock file doesn't exist before I launch Nginx/uwsgi.

Comment: Why do you have `uwsgi_pass` twice in your nginx.conf? Could that be the problem?

Comment: @JoeyWilhelm This is a typo, sorry :(

Comment: @JoeyWilhelm I mean there's only one `uwsgi_pass` in nginx.conf.

Comment: Can you try with `uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;`? I know in the nginx docs they only show one slash, but http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Nginx.html shows the 3

Comment: @JoeyWilhelm Doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to try:
1. make uwsgi_pass the last directive in the location block
2. just for sanity testing purposes, chmod the socket 777 instead of 664. If that resolves it, look into who owns the socket and who nginx is running as.
3. change your uwsgi config to open an HTTP socket on an alternate port and connect to it with your browser, again just for sanity checking purposes.

You also note that the nginx log seems to have no information, but that looks like the nginx access log, not the error log. Does the error log show anything different?

Comment: @AIVaz Thank you so much! I forgot to check Nginx's error log. Turns out it's permission denied problem, and changing to 777 solved it.

Comment: @laike9m You're welcome. It's advisable to look into how you might reduce those permissions again and restrict to the specific user or group that you specify.

Comment: 666 would work. I think it's because Nginx is run by user www-data and uwsgi is run by current logged-in user.